# 3 ScrollViews in a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-widget

What I want to do today is quite trick. I want to make a layout based on a TableLayout, containing 2 TableRows. Inside these tablerows there will be ScrollViews.

I did the layout, but, none of the scrollviews ... scrolls ... I can show you the xml for the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_column="1" android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FF000000">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/testText2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ca cest le trois. Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet sin dolor con mi amor est la melhor que nullum ad quam ergo cum aret. Diligenti am Lubillam am Lubillum."></TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/testText3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ca cest le trois. Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet sin dolor con mi amor est la melhor que nullum ad quam ergo cum aret. Diligenti am Lubillam am Lubillum."></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="100px" android:background="#00FF0000"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/LeftTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:background="#00FF0000" android:text="Ouais !"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollX="20px" android:scrollY="20px" android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llTest2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/android" android:id="@+id/AndroDraw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/testTesttest2" android:text="Test test test!!"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Any Idea ?
Thank you ;) !

Answer (score 0):

i just checked doing
the layout xml i added 2 table row and scroll view inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
                    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/Button02" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:text="@+id/Button15" android:id="@+id/Button15" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:text="@+id/Button14" android:id="@+id/Button14" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:text="@+id/Button13" android:id="@+id/Button13" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/Button03" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
                    <Button android:text="@+id/Button10" android:id="@+id/Button10" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:text="@+id/Button11" android:id="@+id/Button11" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:text="@+id/Button12" android:id="@+id/Button12" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:text="@+id/Button04" android:id="@+id/Button04" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button05" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/Button05"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button06" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/Button06"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button07" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/Button07"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button08" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/Button08"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button09" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/Button09"></Button>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

you can add 3 table Row and do the same

Comment: It's strange. I tested your code, and the whole tableLayout does not fill the screen, (like it wraps the button's text) then I can't see where is the difference with my layout code! However, thanks a lot for you answer !